# Tomcat selecting wrong servlet occasionally

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, url-routing

I have a Java web application that serves up VXML pages to a VXML interpreter. Under sustained traffic conditions in a test lab, Tomcat (6.0.32) appears to be occasionally selecting the wrong servlet to handle the following page request:

```
http://localhost/<myapp>/Main.vxml?<some_query_params_that_get_ignored>
```

Below is the complete list of servlets defined in my web.xml file. According to this, the first servlet should always process the above URL, but in a very small percentage of cases (below 0.1% across 100K+ requests during the course of a weekend), Tomcat routes it to the second servlet (CometControllerServlet).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MainVXML</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/vxml/Main.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainVXML</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Main.vxml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
   <servlet-name>ABPAsync</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.avaya.cc.aaeplite.web.CometControllerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ABPAsync</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/async/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ABP</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ABP</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The following occurrences in the trace output from the most recent traffic run indicate the timing of these... somewhat spread out, so difficult to read anything into.

```
27 16:29:54.880 ERROR <http-6080-exec-2    > [ite.web.CometControllerServlet]  perform() Invalid Request Type: Main.vxml
27 17:36:40.773 ERROR <http-6080-exec-2    > [ite.web.CometControllerServlet]  perform() Invalid Request Type: Main.vxml
27 19:08:18.705 ERROR <http-6080-exec-4    > [ite.web.CometControllerServlet]  perform() Invalid Request Type: Main.vxml
27 19:19:58.799 ERROR <http-6080-exec-5    > [ite.web.CometControllerServlet]  perform() Invalid Request Type: Main.vxml
27 19:49:14.688 ERROR <http-6080-exec-1    > [ite.web.CometControllerServlet]  perform() Invalid Request Type: Main.vxml
27 19:49:34.721 ERROR <http-6080-exec-3    > [ite.web.CometControllerServlet]  perform() Invalid Request Type: Main.vxml
28 07:15:30.835 ERROR <http-6080-exec-7    > [ite.web.CometControllerServlet]  perform() Invalid Request Type: Main.vxml
```

Appreciate any thoughts people might have on why this is happening.

Comment: could you introduce a filter to log the URLs actually requested in these requests?

Comment: Is it possible that a relative url in generated VXML tries to access `/async/Main.vxml`?

Comment: rsp - I've verified from the logs of the VXML interpreter that this isn't the case. 
Gandalf - the VXML interpreter logs this information for me anyway. Good question though. I'm looking to see if something in there is causing me problems. I forgot when posting that the request URL does also include a query part which I'm ignoring at present. I think the url-pattern above should safely handle this though?

Comment: Gandalf - I've confirmed there is nothing distinctive about the request URLs when the error occurs. The only difference in each request is a session id string at the end of the URL, which contains hexadecimal characters only so nothing that could be tripping Tomcat up.

Comment: What is the VXML interpreter you are using? Can you reproduce the issue using a jMeter script to generate load?

Comment: It's a proprietary interpreter. I haven't tried jMeter (wasn't aware of it until now), but I did run a simple batch script polling the URL repetitively for a night and it didn't reproduce the problem. This was a poor effort though as the requests were sequential so not really loading the system. Will look into jMeter.